# Show that $G$ acts faithfully on $S$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $G$ be the group of $2*2$ matrices with determinant
$1$ over the four-element field $F$. Let $S$ be the set of lines through
the origin in $F^2$. Show that $G$ acts faithfully on $S$. (The action is faithful
if the only element of $G$ which fixes every element of $S$ is the identity.)

Comment: Do mean with $F_2$ the vector space $F^2$ over $F$?

Comment: @russoo you are right

Comment: Hint/things to consider: Which matrices of the prescribed form map both the $x$ and $y$-axes to themselves? Can you show that such a matrix has to be diagonal? How many diagonal matrices are in group $G$? Can you show that the non-identity ones move some line other than a coordinate axis?

Comment: I suspect that your question received a downvote, because you didn't include any thoughts and not much context. You could show partial work by including your thoughts on the suggestions in my first comment. The question is otherwise a very good fit on our site, but some users have become sensitive about the site becoming a HW dump. Can you for example tell, why the matrix $$A=\pmatrix{1&1\cr0&1\cr}$$ does not fixe every element of $S$?

Comment: yeah you are right but i a little hard for me to speak English and typing English I'm from Iran this question is not mt HW.